# I want iif conditiomn in my radio button

Tags: asp.net

I want to put if condition in my radio button.

I have wrote this code but it does not give me result as I want. you will get idea from my code what actual I need to do. I have loaded user control two time in a single page so I want to call Java Script in page according to control.

```
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="Pricing" class="2deditable iscreatedbydealer isinprivatelabel"  onClick='<%this.ID=="ucPricing_Details_Sale"? "setSalePopupRetailPrice();":"setClearancePopupRetailPrice();"%>'
                        ID="rbManual" />
```

Comment: `OnClientClick="<%= ` and so on

Answer (score 1):

I think you can dynamic add the onclick event for the control in page load event of server side.

e.g

```
 if("ucPricing_Details_Sale".Equals(this.ID))
 {
     this.rbManual.Attributes.Add("onclick", "setSalePopupRetailPrice();");
 }
 else
 {
     this.rbManual.Attributes.Add("onclick", "setClearancePopupRetailPrice();");
 }
```

Comment: yes I know It will work great. But I need to do it on page side not on class side. means I need it inline code.

Answer (score 0):

The on OnClick event will run on server side. Try using the OnClientClick event instead.

Edit: Deleted my last statement. Mistook me about the context of the call.
Also added code sample:

```
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" 
OnClientClick='<%this.ID=="ucPricing_Details_Sale"?[...]"%>' 
ID="rbManual" />
```